# Login php  session details not passed to admin page

Tags: php, sql-server, session

I have an issue that I cannot figured out,I have tested the same code with two separate servers i.e server A it works well and server B where I need this page to exist is not working.
I need to allow users to log in to the system and catch the log in details to leave announcements.

I have the following code.

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once("dugsi/validation.php");
?>

Form


<form method="post" id="loginForm" action="dugsi/login_validation.php">
            <div>
                <label for="username">User name</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
                <span id="userInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off"/>
                <span id="passwordInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Validation php file

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
session_start();
ob_start();

require_once("dbconnection.php");

login_user();


function login_user()
{
    global $conn;
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $password = hash('sha256', $pass);



    try
    {
        $login_sql =  "SELECT * FROM loginuser WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
        $result = $conn->prepare($login_sql);
        $result->execute(array(':username'=> $username, ':password'=>$password));

        $_SESSION = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $row_count = $result->rowCount();

        if($row_count == 1)
        {



            if ($_SESSION['access_level']  == 1)
            {

            }
            //student 
            else if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 2)
            {
                $student_sql = "SELECT * FROM loginuser, student_module, module,student 
                                     WHERE loginuser.username=student.username 
                                     AND student.username=student_module.student_username 
                                     AND student_module.`module_id` = module.id 
                                     AND loginuser.username= :username";
                $result_student_sql = $conn->prepare($student_sql);
                $result_student_sql->execute(array(':username'=>$username));

                $_SESSION = $result_student_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $module = $_SESSION['module_id'];

                switch ($module)
                {
                    case "ab01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com//dugsi/module/ab01_student.php");
                        break;
                    case "ai01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com//project/module/ai01.php");
                        break;
                    case "fa01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com//project/module/fa01.php");
                        break;
                    case "kh01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com//project/module/kh01.php");
                        break;
                    case "ma01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com//project/module/ma01.php");
                        break;
                    case "ma02":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com//project/module/ma02.php");
                        break;

                }


            }
            //teacher
            else if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 3)
            {
            $teacher_sql = "SELECT * FROM loginuser, teacher_module, module,teacher 
                                     WHERE loginuser.username=teacher.username 
                                     AND teacher.username=teacher_module.teacher_username 
                                     AND teacher_module.`module_id` = module.id 
                                     AND loginuser.username= :username";

                $result_teacher_sql = $conn->prepare($teacher_sql);
                $result_teacher_sql->execute(array(':username'=>$username));

                $_SESSION = $result_teacher_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $module = $_SESSION['module_id'];


                switch ($module)
                {
                    case "ab01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com/dugsi/module/ab01.php");
                        break;
                    case "ai01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com/dugsi/module/ai01.php");
                        break;
                    case "fa01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com/dugsi/module/fa01.php");
                        break;
                    case "kh01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com/dugsi/module/kh01.php");
                        break;
                    case "ma01":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com/dugsi/module/ma01.php");
                        break;
                    case "ma02":
                        header("Location: http://madarasah.com/dugsi/module/ma02.php");
                        break;

                }

            }

            else if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 4) 
            {
                $admin_sql = "SELECT * FROM loginuser, admin 
                                     WHERE loginuser.username=admin.username 
                                     AND loginuser.username= :username";
                $result_admin_sql = $conn->prepare($admin_sql);
                $result_admin_sql->execute(array(':username'=>$username));

                $_SESSION = $result_admin_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                header("Location:http://madarasah.com/dugsi/admin/admin.php");

                exit();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "wrond login details";
        }

    $conn = null;

    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
         printf("Failed to fetch the database. Error: %s",  $exception->getMessage());
    }

}

ob_flush(); 
?>
```

Comment: What are the two domains you are using for normal and admin sites?

Comment: tomziob.co.uk and madarasah.com ,http://www.madarasah.com/dugsi/admin/admin.php and http://www.tomziob.co.uk/dugsi/admin/admin.php

Comment: So the normal site is madarasah.com/ and the admin is madarasah.com/admin

Comment: Sorry mate I might have given you a wrong info.I only need to use one domain in my server,the other one was used just to test if the code will work and it works but when the code is run on this server it does not work

Comment: Here is the admin page :,madarasah.com/dugsi/admin/admin.php, i just need the session to display the details of the login person

Comment: You had migrated to a new domain, and since then the code did not work?

Comment: the server is new and the domain has been registered into this server last week

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16370/discussion-between-somcollection-and-mina-youssef)